# Can I somehow use system wide NO_PROXY to only proxy a couple specific hosts?

Tags: networking, 22.04, internet, proxy, reverse-proxy

I know NO_PROXY is meant to be a blacklist and all other hosts are sent via proxy.  But I am wondering if there is something clever I can do with wildcards and a specific couple hosts to get all hosts except a single one to be part of NO_PROXY?

For example, I want all traffic to be sent without a proxy except example.com and google.com